# Reference for the following topics in Linear Algebra

Tags: reference-request

I'm getting prepared for a [competitive exam](http://csirhrdg.res.in/mcs_netexam_notice.htm) (entirely based on problem solving skill) for which I need to study the following topics in Linear Algebra:

1. Canonical forms,
2. Diagonal forms,
3. Triangular forms,
4. Jordan forms.

Could anyone suggest any lecture notes/referrences which give a quick discussion over the topics? Usually I use *Hoffman-Kunze* text for Linear Algebra. But due to lack of time I don't want to discuss it right now, neither do I stress much on proofs. Please suggest some references according to my need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty much any Linear Algebra text covers those topics, including Schaum's outlines.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Do the results cover in Schaum's provide enough raw materials to think of harder problems e.g. the problems available in https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FBerkeley-Problems-Mathematics-Paulo-Souza%2Fdp%2F0387008926&ei=iQSWUb-DN4rXrQfghID4CA&usg=AFQjCNGyHT7tb5KwGH_fDvQELJKrx5iDSA&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bmk or in http://www.amazon.com/Solutions-Mathematics-Universities-Qualifying-Questions/dp/9814304964/ref=pd_sim_b_2.

Comment: @AnitaArora , yes they do. You can also use very well known general algebra books, like the ones by Hungerford, Dummit&Foote, Gallian, Lang, Bourbaki, Jacobson, Artin, Robinson, Isaacs, etc.....

Comment: @DonAntonio O-M-G

Comment: @Anita, indeed. It only takes up to one semester in university to realize that one needs to dive into the mathematics department's library in order to get a more general vision of things. Bon Apettite!